# Nvim/NERDTree creates file instead of directory

Tags: neovim, nerdtree

I'm using NerdTree in Neovim. To create a folder, in menu I select the

> (a)dd a childnode

option but despite adding a "/" at the end of the foldername a file is being created.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add a "/" at the end of the foldername, rather at the start.